# How add meta tags to <head> after load page?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I add meta tags to `<head>` using PHP?

I have this structure in index.php:

```
<Html>
<Head> ... </ head>
<body> <? php include ($ module); ?> </ Body>
</ Html>
```

Depending on the subpage, I would like to display a different page title. I did the functions meta_tags ($ page) where $ page is the current subpage, but now I have a subpage with an announcement generated from the database. I came up with something like this:

```
<? php ....
$ js. = "<script> $ ('meta [name = \" description \ "]'). attr ('content', '". $ row [' product_title ']. "'); </ script>" ;
?>
```

And it works nicely, but after gluing on FB, it does not read this meta tag.

From what I learned, FB does not see JS and hence the problem.

It all comes down to the fact that he does not want to query the database twice for the title of the product. Once on the subpage of the product, and the second time in the above-mentioned function.

What to do?

Comment: After the page has finished loading there's nothing you can do with PHP to alter it. You're going to have to restructure your project to allow PHP to modify the `<head>` segment of your page.

Comment: Right... PHP runs on the server, so, when the script terminate, your web server send the output to the browser.
So, you have to reconsider your code to build the tags before the content is sent as response by your web server.

Comment: that is, in general I must first generate html through php and display it. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some search engines don't allow the js load while they are crawling, so a good way to do it by PHP.

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

function meta_into_displayer($product_id){

    /*fetch the product data from database here*/


    /*lets you got following array data*/
    $product=[

        "title"=>"Product Title",
        "description"=>"This is product description",

        ];

    return $product;
}

$product_data=meta_into_displayer(1);
echo '
<html>
<head>
   <title>'.$product_data['title'].'</title>
   <meta name="description" content="'.$product_data['description'].'">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>'
?>
```